# ionic 3 ion-avatar visible on page transition

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using `ion-avatar` and `ion-icon` inside my `ion-navbar` toolbar. The problem is it keeps the avatar image and the icon on back pressed page transition. I'm thinking those items are not being animated properly. Here is my code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img [src]="user?.getPicture()" alt="">
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-title>{{ user?.getFirstName() }} {{ user?.getLastName() }}</ion-title>
      <ion-icon name="md-more"></ion-icon>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

`user` is a data from the server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever figured it out?